# Python's cmd.Cmd case insensitive commands

Tags: python

I am using python's CLI module which takes any do_* method and sets it as a command, so a do_show() method will be executed if the user type "show".

How can I execute the do_show() method using any variation of capitalization from user input e.g. ***SHOW, Show, sHoW*** and so on without giving a **Command Not Found** error?

I think the answer would be something to do with overriding the Cmd class and forcing it to take the user's input.lower() but idk how to do that :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override `onecmd` to achieve desired functionality.